# Is it possible to connect to google cloud postgresql from a react app hosted on Firebase Hosting?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, firebase-hosting

I have run out of patience trying to figure out if connecting my react app (hosted on Firebase) to my google cloud postgresql database is possible and how I would go about it.

From what I've read, a Unix socket appears to be the only potential solution but even this approach has yet to yield any success.

Is a Unix socket the answer? Is there another way? If no, is it possible to move my react app over to be hosted on Google App Engine and connect to both Firebase and postgresql there? (the GAE documentation appears as though hosting there could work but once again the endeavor has proven to be rather complicated)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can integrate Firebase with Google Cloud SQL:

1. Set up Firebase and a Google SQL instance.
2. Add the node SQL package to Firebase Functions
3. Add your Google SQL credentials as Functions environment variables.

Here you can find a detailed tutorial about MySQL but the process should be similar for PostgreSQL [link](https://fireship.io/lessons/sql-firebase-typeorm/).

Comment: The problem is that mysql allows you to connect via a tcp connection (as in the tutorial you linked to) whereas you cannot connect to google cloud postgresql with a tcp connection from a browser. Sorry for not being clear about that in the question

Comment: hey @TreyTurner, you cannot connect directly (from the browser **client**) to your database. you will need some kind of server to so. I think marian.vladoi is a convenient solution for you. You can also connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine easily, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine). And connecting to Firebase Firestore (for example) from react is so simple, [link](https://medium.com/get-it-working/get-googles-firestore-working-with-react-c78f198d2364).